# PHP MySQL login function issue

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

I have made a login function only i get a internal server error.
I have checked the function but i don't see the issue.

If i use this:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    if (!isset($username) || !isset($password)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->db->selectOne('r_users', array('username' => trim($username), 'password' => md5(trim($password))))) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION["ipaddr"] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can login into the site

But i want to extend this to get more information from the database for creating the session so i have created this:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    if (!isset($username) || !isset($password)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->db->selectOne('r_users', array('username' => trim($username), 'password' => md5(trim($password))))) {
            $data = array();
            $ps = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `r_users` WHERE `username` = :username');
            $ps->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $ps->execute();
            $result = $ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($result as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
            }
            $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
            $_SESSION["ipaddr"] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but this gives me an internal server error ( 500 ) but i cant see where the problem is.
has anyone a idea?

the site is build on a smarty/slim framework bases and i call this function by jquery/php form

*update: added the FROM to the query see solution 1

Comment: If this is a development system, you should consider turning `display_errors` on. If it's production then `log_errors` and `error_log` so you're able to see the actual error message.

Comment: 500 Internal server error is mainly due to problem in server configuration or .htaccess file. Please check them.

Comment: If you get a 500 error, the PHP log should show what errors you got in the execution of the mentioned code. You should find that log, and check the errors. If you still cannot sort things out, post the last 15 or so lines of the error log.

Comment: there is a [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) (which is supposed to be read first) telling you how to properly connect to PDO to be informed of the errors occurred.

Comment: I have searching for a solution for a while now.
I have read the php.net site about pdo only i don't see the part that have the problem.

I don't see any errors i don't know why i don't see it with all the error log options on.

I have put in one thing that is the FROM into the sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem.

because  i don't see any errors i found out that after i change the query ( i missed the FROM like Yogesh Suthar says ) i find out that the fetch option was not working correctly. So i changed the function to:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    if (!isset($username) || !isset($password)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->db->selectOne('r_users', array('username' => trim($username), 'password' => md5(trim($password))))) {
            $ps = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `r_users` WHERE `username` = :username');
            $ps->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            **$ps->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);**
            $ps->execute();
            **$data = $ps->fetch();**

            $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
            $_SESSION["ipaddr"] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The two highlighted items have i changed.

after this the login function is working great.

Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `from` in query

```
$ps = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `r_users` WHERE `username` = :username');
                                   ^ here is problem
```

Comment: I have fixed this only this is not the end solution.

I have still the error only the logs and PHP display errors gives me notthing

Answer (score 0):

`internal server error ( 500 )` means "Look into servers error log".
So, you have to find the error log and read the error message.